# Google and Apple Sign-in Firebase not working in TestFlight for expo app

Tags: react-native, expo, single-sign-on, react-native-firebase

I am working on an app that requires SignIn with Apple and Google via FireBase.
In development mode, signIn was working fine with both. But after deploying it in TestFlight, I cannot SignIn with Them anymore.

also the code for SignIn with Google and Apple :

```
Google:
import * as Google from "expo-google-app-auth";
try {
  const result = await Google.logInAsync({
    iosClientId:
      "##############.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    scopes: ["profile", "email"],
  });

  if (result.type === "success") {
    const { idToken, accessToken } = result;
    const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      idToken,
      accessToken
    );

    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    user.linkWithCredential(credential).then(async () => {}
```

---

```
Apple:
import * as AppleAuthentication from "expo-apple-authentication";
import * as Crypto from "expo-crypto";
    try {
      const csrf = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
      const nonce = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 10);
      const hashedNonce = await Crypto.digestStringAsync(
        Crypto.CryptoDigestAlgorithm.SHA256,
        nonce
      );
      const appleCredential = await AppleAuthentication.signInAsync({
        requestedScopes: [
          AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationScope.FULL_NAME,
          AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationScope.EMAIL,
        ],
        state: csrf,
        nonce: hashedNonce,
      });
      const { identityToken, email, state } = appleCredential;

      if (identityToken) {
        const provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider("apple.com");
        const credential = provider.credential({
          idToken: identityToken,
          rawNonce: nonce, // nonce value from above
        });
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        user.linkWithCredential(credential).then(async () => {})}
```